# Múltiples Wordpress en docker-compose

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, traefik

tengo un docker-compose.yml donde tengo los siguientes contenedores.

```
traefik
wp1
db1
wp2
db2
```

tengo 2 wordpress y 2 mysql, estos contenedores son gestionados por traefik, el tema es que cuando levanto estos contenedores con el comando `docker-compose p -d` una de las bases de datos se cae y no logro levantar las dos al mismo tiempo, creo que mi problema pasa por el puerto, ya que los dos estan usando el `3306` sin embargo gue probado cambiado los puertos pero nada, siempre hay una de las bases de datos que no corre.

este es mi archivo `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
    services: 
      reverse-proxy:
        image: traefik:v2.1
        container_name: traefik
        ports: 
          - 443:443
          - 80:80
          - 8080:8080
        volumes: 
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
          - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
          - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.sitio1.com`)
          - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
          - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.port=8080
          - traefik.docker.network=web
        networks:
          - web
          - inmobiliaria
    
    ######### sitio1 ###########
    
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: db
        env_file: .env
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
          MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
        labels: 
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        ports: 
          - 3307:3306
        volumes: 
          - ./sitio1/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          - web
    
      wp:
        build:
          context: . 
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: wp
        env_file: .env
        labels: 
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.wp.rule=Host(`dominio1.com`)
          - traefik.http.routers.wp.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.wp.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.port=9000
        links:
          - db
        volumes:
          - ./sitio1/src:/var/www/html
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}"
        networks:
          - web
    
      phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        env_file: .env
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: ${PMA_HOST}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`pa.dominio1.com`)
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.port=80
        networks:
          - web
    
    
      ####### sitio2 ########
    
      db-inmobiliaria:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: db-inmobiliaria
        env_file: .env
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_INMOBILIARIA}"
          MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER_INMOBILIARIA}"
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD_INMOBILIARIA}"
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_INMOBILIARIA}"
        labels: 
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        ports: 
          - 3308:3306
        volumes: 
          - ./sitio2/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          - inmobiliaria
    
      wp-inmobiliaria:
        build:
          context: . 
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: wp-inmobiliaria
        labels: 
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.wp-inmobiliaria.rule=Host(`dominio2.com`)
          - traefik.http.routers.wp-inmobiliaria.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.wp-inmobiliaria.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.port=9000
        links:
          - db-inmobiliaria
        volumes:
          - ./sitio2/src:/var/www/html
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST_INMOBILIARIA}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME_INMOBILIARIA}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${WORDPRESS_DB_USER_INMOBILIARIA}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD_INMOBILIARIA}"
        networks:
          - inmobiliaria
    
      phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria:
        depends_on:
          - db-inmobiliaria
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria
        restart: always
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: ${PMA_HOST_INMOBILIARIA}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_INMOBILIARIA}
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria.rule=Host(`pa.dominio2.com`)
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.port=80
        networks:
          - inmobiliaria
    
    networks:
      web:
       driver: "bridge"
      inmobiliaria:
        driver: "bridge"
```

mis contenedores

```
    root@ubuntu-serve:~/sites# docker-compose ps 
         Name                        Command                State                                  Ports                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db                        docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up         3306/tcp                                                        
db-inmobiliaria           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Exit 137                                                                   
phpmyadmin                /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up         80/tcp                                                          
phpmyadmin-inmobiliaria   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up         80/tcp                                                          
traefik                   /entrypoint.sh traefik           Up         0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
wp                        docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up         80/tcp, 9000/tcp                                                
wp-inmobiliaria           docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up         80/tcp, 9000/tcp
```

Comment: sería interesante ver los logs de la db que cae.. eso normalmente da pistas. Y como ya te han dicho el código 137 es un OOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le paso lo mismo, la Solución es que `estaba corriendo mis servicios en un servidor con poca memoria RAM,` aumenté la memoria y ahora todo funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

El contenedor te ha dado un error Exit code 137 - Out of memory, prueba a ejecutar docker-compose sin el parámetro -d para más información en el log

Comment: La solución era que estaba corriendo todos mis servicios en un servidor con poca memoria RAM, por lo tanto lo solucione aumentando la memoria y todo funciona bien ahora, gracias por responder, saludos.